# OnClick SVGicon not working - React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi I am having an icon in my header component. There I have placed a one svg icon by clicking that I need to display another component(My Account).  I created a another component called my account where I split the page in to two parts and I am displaying both Login and Register and ProductSlider component. When I tried to add onClick and dipslay the component it's not displaying the component. In routes I configured the same component by giving a path("my-account). when I click that button I need to navigate to this path so I tried using useNavigate inside MyAccount component itself but I got an error saying that useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component. I have gone through few topics but I am unable to get it right. Anybody can help me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
//Main Header component
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function MainHeader() {
  //   const history = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = () => <MyAccount />;

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="light" className="main-header">
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
          <Col sm={2}>
            <img
              src="/assets/images/beelittle-logo.webp"
              alt="logo"
              className="logo"
            />
          </Col>
          <Col sm={7}>
            <div className="search-input">
              <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
              <div className="search-icon">
                <svg
                  version="1.1"
                  className="dgwt-wcas-ico-magnifier"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 51.539 51.361"
                  enable-background="new 0 0 51.539 51.361"
                >
                  <path
                    fill="#444"
                    d="M51.539,49.356L37.247,35.065c3.273-3.74,5.272-8.623,5.272-13.983c0-11.742-9.518-21.26-21.26-21.26 S0,9.339,0,21.082s9.518,21.26,21.26,21.26c5.361,0,10.244-1.999,13.983-5.272l14.292,14.292L51.539,49.356z M2.835,21.082 c0-10.176,8.249-18.425,18.425-18.425s18.425,8.249,18.425,18.425S31.436,39.507,21.26,39.507S2.835,31.258,2.835,21.082z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={3}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-evenly ">
              <div className="d-flex">
                <div onClick={handleClick}>
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    width="28"
                    height="30"
                    viewBox="0 0 28 30"
                    fill="none"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M13.9789 11.9586C16.9498 11.9586 19.3582 9.55022 19.3582 6.57931C19.3582 3.6084 16.9498 1.2 13.9789 1.2C11.008 1.2 8.59961 3.6084 8.59961 6.57931C8.59961 9.55022 11.008 11.9586 13.9789 11.9586Z"
                      fill="#90D2C2"
                    ></path>
                    <path
                      d="M14.0004 13.2C10.3605 13.2 7.40039 10.2399 7.40039 6.6C7.40039 2.9601 10.3605 0 14.0004 0C17.6403 0 20.6004 2.9601 20.6004 6.6C20.6004 10.2399 17.6403 13.2 14.0004 13.2ZM14.0004 2.475C11.725 2.475 9.87539 4.32465 9.87539 6.6C9.87539 8.87535 11.725 10.725 14.0004 10.725C16.2757 10.725 18.1254 8.87535 18.1254 6.6C18.1254 4.32465 16.2757 2.475 14.0004 2.475Z"
                      fill="black"
                    ></path>
                    <path
                      d="M25.9623 30C25.2792 30 24.7248 29.4456 24.7248 28.7625V24.6375C24.7248 21.6807 22.3191 19.275 19.3623 19.275H8.6373C5.6805 19.275 3.2748 21.6807 3.2748 24.6375V28.7625C3.2748 29.4456 2.7204 30 2.0373 30C1.3542 30 0.799805 29.4456 0.799805 28.7625V24.6375C0.799805 20.3162 4.31595 16.8 8.6373 16.8H19.3623C23.6837 16.8 27.1998 20.3162 27.1998 24.6375V28.7625C27.1998 29.4456 26.6454 30 25.9623 30Z"
                      fill="black"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                My Account
              </div>

//MY Account Component 
function MyAccount() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
          <Col>
            <h2 className="title">My Account</h2>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Login />
          </Col>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Register />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      <section className="bg-grey">
        <ProductSlider />
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

//App.js
<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/my-account" element={<MyAccount />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/product" element={<Product />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. The `handleClick` is an asynchronous event handler so it can't return JSX and have it rendered. `handleClick` should invoke the `navigate` function to issue an imperative navigation action to the route rendering `<MyAccount>`.
2. You appear to be wrapping individual `Route` components each in their own `Routes` component, just render all sibling `Route`s into a single `Routes` component.
3. You don't show where `MainHeader` is rendered, but it necessarily needs to be rendered within the same `BrowserRouter` rendering the routes.

## Solution

Main Header component

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function MainHeader() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => navigate("/my-account");

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="light" className="main-header">
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
          <Col sm={2}>
            <img
              src="/assets/images/beelittle-logo.webp"
              alt="logo"
              className="logo"
            />
          </Col>
          <Col sm={7}>
            <div className="search-input">
              <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
              <div className="search-icon">
                <svg
                  ...
                >
                  ...
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={3}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-evenly ">
              <div className="d-flex">
                <div onClick={handleClick}>
                  <svg
                    ...
                  >
                    ...
                  </svg>
                </div>
                My Account
              </div>

          ...
```

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <MainHeader />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/my-account" element={<MyAccount />} />
    <Route path="/product" element={<Product />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error  useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a component.

Comment: @Still_Learning What exactly is the error and what are you trying to do? The `useNavigate` hook can only be used in React functions, `MainHeader` is React function component (*the first part of my answer*), and it only needs to be used within a routing context, `MainHeader` is rendered within `BrowserRouter` (*the second part of my answer*). These are about the only requirements necessary. If it's not working then you're still doing something incorrectly that you haven't shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

let navigate = useNavigate();

const handleClick = () => navigate("/my-account");
```

Comment: but how can I pass this onclick to that SVG icon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping Routes in App.js, I wrapped entire App component inside Router. It's working now!

```
 <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
```